# what is /data/configdb path used for in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, docker

I am running a docker of mongodb, and notice a volume created and mounted to /data/configdb. this is in addition to another volume mapped to /data/db which I know is where my actual data is stored.

I am trying to find out what is stored in /data/configdb, and searched google for it. surprisingly enough I didn't find anything explaining what is stored there.

what is stored there (/data/configdb), and can it be discarded everytime I restart my mongodb container?

Comment: Which docker image are you using for mongodb. Please mention the image details.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To summarize from the docs, config servers store the metadata for a sharded cluster, and `/data/configdb` is the default path where a config server stores its data files. So if you're not dealing with sharded clusters, removing any references to it should be ok.

From the docs:

> `--configsvr`
>
> Declares that this mongod instance serves as the config server of a sharded cluster. When running with this option, clients (i.e. other cluster components) will not be able to write data to any database other than config and admin. The default port for a mongod with this option is `27019` and the default `--dbpathdirectory` is `/data/configdb`, unless specified.

References:

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/sharded-cluster-config-servers/

https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.4/reference/program/mongod/#cmdoption-configsvr

Hope this helps!

Comment: your answer is very helpful ... but i want to ask about this kind of cluster ? till now i am running mongodb as default adding data and getting this data ? how can i understand what is a cluster or how to work with ? do you have any references ?

Answer (score 0):

I have deployed docker image of mongodb https://hub.docker.com/_/mongo on OpenShift it generated out of the box the deployment.yaml file which contains part with two volumeMounts:

```
 - mountPath: /data/configdb
   name: mongo-5-0-1
 - mountPath: /data/db
   name: mongo-5-0-2
```

When I want to use single not sharded database server and store my data into volume, this is how this part of deployment.yaml should look like

```
  volumes:
    - name: mongo-5-0-1
      emptyDir: {}
    - name: mongo-5-0-2
      persistentVolumeClaim:
        claimName: myVolumeName
```

In image documentation it's mentioned that:

> This image also defines a volume for /data/configdb for use with
> --configsvr (see docs.mongodb.com for more details).